Entropy Production Rates
I am trying to reproduce the results shown in Fig. 2(a) of the paper https://journals.aps.org/prresearch/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevResearch.6.033037 to calculate entropy production rates in a cavity magnomechanical system.
I have formulated the Lyapunov equation for the drift matrix A, covariance matrix V, and diagonal matrix  but I am encountering issues when solving for the covariance matrix elements. My current implementation does not seem to match the expected results from the paper.
Could anyone provide guidance or suggestions on the correct approach to solving this problem, or point out any possible mistakes in the process? Any advice on reproducing the specific entropy production rates shown in Fig. 2(a) would be greatly appreciated!

    ClearAll;
(*Define constants*)
gam = 0;
Nb = 10;
Nm = 10^-3;
omegab = 2 \[Pi]*10*10^6;(*phonon frequency*)
\[Gamma]a = 2 \[Pi]*3*10^6;(*cavity dissipation rate*)
\[Gamma]m = omegab/2;(*magnon dissipation rate*)
\[Gamma]b = 0.001*omegab;(*phonon damping rate*)
Gmb = 0.1*omegab;

(*Define the drift matrix A*)
A = {{0, gam, -\[Gamma]m, \[CapitalDelta]m*omegab}, {-gam, 
    0, -\[CapitalDelta]m*omegab, -\[Gamma]m}, {0, 0, 0, omegab}, {0, 
    0, Gmb, -\[Gamma]b - omegab}};

(*Define the diagonal matrix D (corresponding to a 4x4 system)*)
DD = DiagonalMatrix[{\[Gamma]m (2 Nm + 1), \[Gamma]m (2 Nm + 
       1), \[Gamma]b (2 Nb + 1), \[Gamma]b (2 Nb + 1)}];

(*Define the symbolic covariance matrix V as a 4x4 matrix*)
V = Array[Vij, {4, 4}];

(*Solve the Lyapunov equation A V+V Transpose[A]+D=0 for the elements \
of V*)
solution = Solve[A.V + Transpose[A].V + DD == 0, Flatten[V]];

(*Extract the solution and display it in matrix form*)
covarianceMatrix = V /. solution // MatrixForm;

(*Extract the necessary elements from the solved covariance matrix*)
V11 = Vij[1, 1] /. solution;
V22 = Vij[2, 2] /. solution;
V33 = Vij[3, 3] /. solution;
V44 = Vij[4, 4] /. solution;

(*Define the entropy production rate s*)
entropyProductionRate = 
  2 \[Gamma]m ((V11 + V22)/(2 Nm + 1) - 1) + 
   2 \[Gamma]b ((V33 + V44)/(2 Nb + 1) - 1);

(*Plot the entropy production rate*)
Plot[entropyProductionRate, {\[CapitalDelta]m , -6, 6}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Dashed}, PlotRange -> All]


It is not clear why you are using a 4x4 model instead of a 6x6 one?

@AlexTrounev  Because I want to calculate the effective entropy flow between the
magnon mode and the mechanical resonator.

Is it your sentence in the beginning of this post: "I am trying to reproduce the results shown in Fig. 2(a) of the paper"? Please, note, that in the paper they used 6x6 matrix. :)

@AlexTrounev but if you look at the Eq. 8 in the paper the steady state for entropy are depends on the v_33, v_44, v_55 and v_66. Anyway, I will appreciate your useful suggestions on this.
